# Regex: Find pagenumber from partial matching urls

Tags: c#, regex

As we all know, Regex patterns will make your stomache turn the first time you see them (or 10th time since you never went head first and truly learned it. Quilty.). I'm currently reading upon it, but since I'm on a tight deadline I'll check here if I can get a quicker and better answer/explaination meanwhile.

I have some url to a forum thread, and I want to scan through the html and find the last page for the thread.

So say I have one of the following urls identifying the thread in question:

- https://www.somesite.com/forum/thread-93912* (absolute url to the
  thread)
- */forum/thread-93912* (relative url to the thread)

and I want to get all values (integers) that appear directly (next path) after any of the above "partial" match in the html-document.

So from any of the following hrefs **located anywhere in the html-document** (the doc is represented as a single string):

- https://www.somesite.com/forum/thread-93912/34
- https://www.somesite.com/forum/thread-93912/34/morestuffhere/whatevs
- /forum/thread-93912/34
- /forum/thread-93912/34/somethingheretoo

I want to **extract** the number 34 (only 34), so I can parse it to int.

**EDIT**

Okay, to make it simpler:

Say I have all the html in `htmlString`, and in this string I want to find *all* numbers **x** that appear after my inputString `/forum/thread-93912`.

These all appear in the `htmlString`, and I want to extract the numbers:

- thread-93912/**34**
- thread-93912/**14**
- thread-93912/**84**
- thread-93912/**64**
- thread-93912/**4**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since my question was a little hard to explain thuroughly (and since I "changed" my problem a little), I thought I'd add my own answer to get the exact code I went with (which I came up with thanks to the other answers here, so I'll give you all an upvote!).*

I'm sure this can be made prettier and more compact, but I went for clearity since I'm new to regex!

**First**, get all strings matching the url + some number (separated with a slash "/"), then extract that number to a group called "page".

```
Regex regex = new Regex(urlToThread + @"/(?<page>\d+)");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(htmlString);
```

**Then** iterate all matches and extract the "page"-value (garanteed to be an integer), and parse it to an integer. Add all parsed integers to a list and sort when done. The last one will be the greatest (last page).

```
List<int> pages = new List<int>();
foreach(Match match in matches)
    pages.Add(int.Parse(match.Groups["page"].Value));
pages.Sort();
// And here we get the last page
int nrOfPages = pages[pages.Count-1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex. Just use [`System.Uri.Segments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Uri url = new Uri("your url here");
Console.WriteLine(url.Segments[4]);
```

Comment: This could work but then I'll have to loop through the segments and find the first number _after_ the "last segment" of the matching url. I don't always know before hand at what segment the page-value is.
Also, I first have to get all the matching hrefs in the html, then loop the segments for each. Would be perferable if it could all be solved with a concise regex pattern.

Comment: @helmesjo You don't need to loop through the segment. you can just do `url.Segments[(url.Segments.IndexOf(Thread-93912) + 1)]`, which always finds the segment RIGHT after that last segment.

Comment: Implicit loop though ;) But yeah, I see. Atleast with this I'm not fumbling off with regex patterns I have no clue how they work... 
I'll wait until I've tried a few solutions, but if none work as expected I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @helmesjo non-regex solution for this problem is *always* better than with regex, just sayin

Comment: Yep, I'm have that feeling too looking over the problem in question. Especially when I know jack about regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(\d+)\b(?=[^\d]*$)
```

Try this.See demo.grab the capture.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/55

using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b\d+\b(?=[^\d]*$)");
    Match match = regex.Match("/forum/thread-93912/34");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lawd have mercy, this must have been the fastest answer in history. I'll try it out!

Comment: Oh sorry. Tried it now but since I don't even know how to decifer regex I'm not sure what I'm looking at. In your demo-page, where would I input that the part before the pagenumber should be a partial match of the thread url? Or do I have to try it with Regex.Match? As I stated, I know zip about this. :)

Comment: Oh, I saw you're using the wrong input for the match-check. I want to look for any partial match to '/forum/thread-93912' in 'someHtmlString', and get all the numbers after the match so to speak. Let me know if I'm not really clear about it, hard to explain!

Comment: Okey, I see what I explained wrong... The latter hrefs in my post (https://www.somesite.com/forum/thread-93912/34   etc.), are not actually found yet. They are "somewhere" in a html-document represented as a single string.
 **updated post**

Comment: @helmesjo can you post the string?

Comment: Sure, look at this page: http://www.familjeliv.se/forum/thread/72859242-vi-runt-35-ar-som-vantar-barn

I have that url, and inside this page (having the html), I want to find the laste page '48' which is written as this: _/forum/thread/72859242-vi-runt-35-ar-som-vantar-barn/48_. So knowing the url, and knowing the html (which contains the relative url) I want to **extract** the number 48.